# Proof of the generalised complex number triangle inequality without induction

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, triangles, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Does anyone have a proof of the generalised complex number triangle inequality that doesn't involve induction... is there one?

Thanks

Comment: A straight line is the shortest distance between two points. (It rather depends what you are allowed to assume)

Comment: By generalised triangle inequality, do you mean $|z_1 + \cdots + z_n| \leq |z_1| +\cdots + |z_n|$? Also, why don't you want to involve induction? I think it would be difficult to do it entirely without induction, since the indices are natrual numbers, and induction is at the heart of the definition of the natural numbers. You might be able to do it without explicitly inducing on the indices, but it happpens under the hood anyways, so why not be honest about it?

Comment: I am just curious for another proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$|z_1|+|z_2|+...+|z_n|\geq|z_1+z_2+...+z_n|.$$
Indeed, let $z_k=a_k+b_ki,$ where $\{a_k,b_k\}\subset\mathbb R$.

Thus, by C-S
$$\sum_{k=1}^n|z_k|=\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{a_k^2+b_k^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\sqrt{(a_i^2+b_i^2)(a_j^2+b_j^2)}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\sqrt{(a_ia_j+b_ib_j)^2}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}|a_ia_j+b_ib_j|}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(a_ia_j+b_ib_j)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^nb_k\right)^2}=|z_1+z_2+...+z_n|$$
and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

$$
|z_1 + \cdots + z_n|^2 = (z_1 + \cdots + z_n)(\bar z_1 + \cdots + \bar z_n) \\
= |z_1|^2 +\cdots + |z_n|^2 +  \sum_{i < j}(z_i \bar z_j + \bar z_i z_j) \\
= |z_1|^2 +\cdots + |z_n|^2 + 2 \sum_{i < j} \operatorname{Re}(z_i \bar z_j ) \\
\le |z_1|^2 +\cdots + |z_n|^2 + 2 \sum_{i < j} |z_i  z_j | 
= (|z_1| +\cdots + |z_n|)^2 \, .
$$

Equality holds if $z_i \bar z_j$ is a non-negative real number for all
$i, j$, that is if all non-zero $z_i$ are a positive multiple of each other.

Comment: I think it's my solution exactly.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: You used real numbers and C-S, I used complex numbers and properties like $w + \bar w = 2 \operatorname{Re} w$ and  $\operatorname{Re w} \le |w|$. It is a different view at the problem, and – I my opinion – worth a separate answer.

Comment: In my opinion you just took my idea and wrote it in another form. I think it's not fair.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I definitely did *not* do that.